# Minting throws ERC20: mint to the zero address

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

I'm building an ERC20 token using OpenZeppelin's ERC20 base contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 20 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

And I deploy it using this code in nodejs:

```
async deployContract(account: Account, compiled: any): Promise<TransactionReceipt> {
    const contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(compiled.contracts["contract.sol"]["MyToken"].abi);
    return contract.deploy({ data: "0x" + compiled.contracts["contract.sol"]["MyToken"].evm.bytecode.object });
    
    const signed = await account.signTransaction({
        from: account.address,
        data: contract.encodeABI(),
        gas: Math.floor((await contract.estimateGas()) * 1.1),
        gasPrice: await this.web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
    });

    return this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
}
```

But the execution breaks at the account.signTransaction method giving the following error:

```
Error: Returned error: execution reverted: ERC20: mint to the zero address
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/***/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /***/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:302:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/***/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
```

I guess msg.sender has the zero address, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It is missing `to` field in `signTransaction`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a REALLY frustrating problem.

In my case, I was using Infura, so I thought of course the addr couldn't be zero.

What I realized is that for some reason `msg.sender` wasn't coming out the way it was supposed to.

Here's what I ended up doing in my contract; I passed an owner to the contract and used that as my initial _mint.

That is what solved this for me. I hope this saves someone from wasting 5 hours on this like I did.

```
  address public OWNER;

  constructor(
    string memory name,
    string memory symbol,
    uint256 initialSupply,
    address payable owner
  ) payable ERC20(name, symbol) {
    OWNER = owner;
    _mint(OWNER, initialSupply);
  }
```